# Append file name to beginning of [Markdown] file recursively

Tags: shell-script, shell, recursive, markdown

I have a folder with a whole lot of folders with a whole lot of Markdown files in each. What I'd like to do is recursively (if possible) prepend the file name as a heading in each file.

So, given `foo.md`:

```
The cat sat on the carpet, which is really just endless mat to a cat.
```

I'd like:

```
# Foo.md

The cat sat on the carpet, which is really just endless mat to a cat.
```

I'm not bothered about the file extension. I am bothered that it is a valid Markdown heading 1 with a line afterwards.

---

My file structure looks like

```
md/
  foo/
    heaps.md
    and.md
  bar/
    heaps.md
    of.md
  baz/
    files.md
    omg.md
```

and so on and so forth. *Ideally,* I'd love something that I can copy into a .sh or similar, but a one-liner would be nice too!

Cheers.

Comment: `Foo.md` with first letter upper cased or exactly like the filename?

Comment: Not bothered, either way is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bash's globstar and ed plus some P.E., I suggest you try with some sample data/directory first.

```
shopt -s globstar

for f in md/**/*.md; do 
  header=${f##*/} header=${header^}
  printf '%s\n' 0a "# $header" "" . w | ed -s "$f"
done
```

Or the one liner but remember to set `globstar`

```
for f in md/**/*.md; do header=${f##*/} header=${header^}; printf '%s\n' 0a "# $header" "" . w | ed -s "$f" ; done
```

To check the content of the files while globstar is still on you could try.

```
tail -n+1  md/**/*.md
```

`0` is the address or line number in the buffer and `a` is the action which means `append` or `add`

The extra `""` is to create an empty line before the next line in the file.

Although `1i` (which means Insert at line number one) instead of `0a`  will work also but for empty files it will fail.

`.` tells ed that were done editing the file and `w` means write it to the file

piping `|` to `ed` and  `-s` which means silent and not output anything to `stdout`.

The rest is just some variable assigiment and P.E. from the bash shell.

Comment: Sorry, might be having a moment here, but what's P.E.?

Comment: Parameter Expansion. try   `PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*Parameter\ Expansion' man bash`

Comment: ah, cheers, homie

Comment: It worked! You're a real one, my dude <3

Comment: Sure thing, homie :-)